# Python loop with address locator

Tags: python, arcpy, geocoding

I was given a list of addresses without any zip codes, and I'm trying to write a python snippet that will loop through a set of possible zip codes and make a set of geocoded shapefiles that I will later merge.

My address table is essentially laid out like this: ("Project_" fields are the possible zip codes)

```
Address          City        Project_1   Project_2  ...  Project_42  
123 Main Street  Birmingham  78954       78953      ...  78961
```

My python snippet looks like this:

```
import arcpy  
from arcpy import env  
env.workspace = "N:\Reference\GIS\State\Project\Address Locator"  
geocoder = env.workspace + "\State_Addresses_Create_Addr"  
for y in range(1,43):  
    zippo = "Projects_" + str(y)  
    outfile = '"N:\Project_Geocode_Results_'+ str(y) + '"'  
    fncgeo = '"Street Apartment VISIBLE NONE; ZIP ' + zippo + ' VISIBLE"'  
    arcpy.GeocodeAddresses_geocoding("Geocode_Table", geocoder, fncgeo, outfile)
```

When I try to run the snippet outside of a loop (i.e., based on a single field), the geocode works fine. When I run it as written above, I get:

> ERROR 000010: Geocode addresses failed. Failed to execute (Geocode Addresses).

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the geocode won't work in a loop?

Comment: One other thing that might be contributing to the problem is the backslash character... for simplicity I always use the forward slash in paths, even though in Windows it doesn't look right...  anywhere there is a back slash, change it to a forward slash...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the extra double quote is the issue in the outfile and fncgeo variable. Try this:

```
import arcpy  
from arcpy import env  
env.workspace = "N:\Reference\GIS\State\Project\Address Locator"  
geocoder = env.workspace + "\State_Addresses_Create_Addr"  
for y in range(1,43):  
    zippo = "Projects_" + str(y)  
    outfile = r'N:\Project_Geocode_Results_{0}.shp'.format(y) 
    fncgeo = 'Street Apartment VISIBLE NONE; ZIP {0} VISIBLE'.format(zippo)  
    arcpy.GeocodeAddresses_geocoding("Geocode_Table", geocoder, fncgeo, outfile)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion made the loop work; only problem now is that the background server is throwing an exception on the third or fourth loop every time. It won't run in the foreground either--crashes after three or four loops. But your fix definitely got the loop going--thanks!

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting that error, especially after it completes a few iterations of the loop.  Are the few outputs that do get created correct?  Maybe you could add a time.sleep(5) after the geocode.  Not sure if that would help or not but could be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks again! As you suggested, I added time.sleep(5) to the end of the loop, and it looped all the way to the end of the range. I guess Arc just needed its beauty rest.

Comment: Wow, that is funny. I cannot believe that worked. I'm glad you're up and running now.